# How does Google Drawing work?

Tags: web-applications, google-docs

just wondering what is behind the major functionalities used in Google Drawing. Does it use jQuery?

Comment: Google is all about hand rolling its own JavaScript. No client libraries for them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They render the pictures using SVG and use their own javascript libraries for the user interface.